# Colour overlay on hover with css - .png image

Tags: html, css, overlay, squarespace

I'm trying to create a colour overlay on hover effect for my website. I'm displaying clients/customers. (like so: http://www.squarespace.com/customers/) - but I'd like to change it specifically to a blue overlay, not reduce the images opacity.

Here's where I've got thus far

https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/d98sv4cy/

I'm wondering is there an easy way to do this with css - like using a colour mask so that covers the png logo only. I've been reading about the `overflow: hidden;` property but am not sure how to implement it.

Your help would be appreciated, and I sincerely hope this is possible!! (Thank you to those who have answered already)

I'm developing the website using Squarespace to css solutions would be appreciated as opposed to jquery/javascript.

Comment: You might wanna use CSS-filters https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use transitions, they are widely supported now. This is based on the code you've provided:

```
.icon div:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, can I change the opacity property to add a coloured filter instead? Perhaps using RBG value of any colour with opacity .5?

Comment: You could stack two images one on top of the other. The very first one is coloured, the one above it is b&w. Then using transitions again just fade the top image to become fully transparent - you'll end up with coloured one.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought I was going to have to do. I thought there might have been an easier way rather than opening photoshop. Many thanks!

Comment: You could also try filter: grayscale(100%);  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: gray;  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick, use opacity and transition https://jsfiddle.net/d98sv4cy/1/

```
.icon:hover {
    opacity: .33;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is [CSS blend modes](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) something you'd consider?